# The C++ Programming Language - Bjarne Stroustrup. Tuple example

Tags: c++

I have a question about this example from the book: The C++ Programming Language (Bjarne Stroustrup):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Nil {};

template <typename T0 = Nil, typename T1 = Nil, typename T2 = Nil, typename T3 = Nil>
struct Tuple : public Tuple <T1, T2, T3> 
{
    T0 x;

    using Base = Tuple<T1, T2, T3>;
    Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this);};
    const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this);};

    Tuple(const T0& t0, const T1& t1, const T2& t2, const T3& t3 ) : Base{t1, t2, t3}, x{t0} {};
};

template <>
struct Tuple<> 
{
    Tuple() {};
};

template <typename T0>
struct Tuple<T0> : Tuple<>
{
    T0 x;

    using Base = Tuple<>;
    Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this);};
    const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this);};

    Tuple(const T0& t0 ) : Base{}, x{t0} {};
};

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct Tuple<T0, T1> : public Tuple <T1> 
{
    T0 x;

    using Base = Tuple<T1>;
    Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this);};
    const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this);};

    Tuple(const T0& t0, const T1& t1) : Base{t1}, x{t0} {};
};

template <typename T0 , typename T1, typename T2>
struct Tuple<T0, T1, T2> : public Tuple <T1, T2> 
{
    T0 x;

    using Base = Tuple<T1, T2>;
    Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this);};
    const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this);};

    Tuple(const T0& t0, const T1& t1, const T2& t2) : Base{t1, t2}, x{t0} {};
};

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void print_Tuple(std::ostream &os, const Tuple<T0, T1, T2, T3>& t) {
    os << t.x << ", ";
    print_Tuple(os, *t.base());
}

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
void print_Tuple(std::ostream &os, const Tuple<T0, T1, T2>& t) {
    os << t.x << ", ";
    print_Tuple(os, *t.base());
}

template <typename T0, typename T1>
void print_Tuple(std::ostream &os, const Tuple<T0, T1>& t) {
    os << t.x << ", ";
    print_Tuple(os, *t.base());
}

template <typename T0>
void print_Tuple(std::ostream &os, const Tuple<T0>& t) {
    os << t.x;
}

template <>
void print_Tuple(std::ostream &os, const Tuple<>& t) {
    os <<  " ";
}

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Tuple<T0, T1, T2, T3> t) {
    os << "{";
    print_Tuple(os, t);
    os << "}";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Tuple<int, double, char, bool> t4(1, 1.5, 'a', true);
    std::cout << t4 << std::endl;

    Tuple<int, double> t2(2, 2.5);
    std::cout << t2 << std::endl;
}
```

This code works fine.

We need 4 functions like "print_Tuple" and it is clear to me. but why there is only function: "std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Tuple<T0, T1, T2, T3> t)"? How does this function handle the example with 2 tuples (Without T2 and T3 elelents)?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: There are overloads of the `print_Tuple` method to handle the different number.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the code works for tuples of 1, 2, 3 and 4 items.

Comment: I am debugging it. A tuple always contains 4 objects, but a few of them may be defalut (Nil). For example "Tuple<int, double> t2(2, 2.5);" is "Tuple<int, double, Nil, Nil>. So I know why one function "operator <<" can cover all examples.

But how is it possible to call "void print_Tuple(std::ostream &os, const Tuple<T0, T1>& t)" if a tuple has always 4 objects (a few can be Nil)?

Comment: Remember that `template <typename T0, typename T1> void print_Tuple(std::ostream& os, const Tuple<T0, T1>& t)` is an exact match for `template <typename T0, typename T1> void print_Tuple(std::ostream& os, const Tuple<T0, T1, Nil, Nil>& t)`.  The `Nil` are default types.

Comment: Great, thank you! This helps me :)

The last thing that is not clear to me is how to construct Tuple<int, double, Nil, Nil> object using Tuple(const T0& t0, const T1& t1) constructor?

Comment: The `Tuple(const T0& t0, const T1& t1)` constructor is for a `Tuple<T0,T1,Nil,Nil>` partially specialized type.